# 14.04.3 xrdp "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" not Work

Tags: xrdp

I installed ubuntu 14.04.3

I installed xwindows

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot

sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

and .xsession setting..

```
echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > ~/.xsession
sudo service xrdp restart
```

and windows 7 - remote desktop connect

id & password insert -> login ok.

My Screen

```
all grey.. center "X" mark..
2~3 seconds later screen close!
```

Why not connect "Ubuntu 14.04.3" "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" or 
"gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback" session?

Answer (score 1):

unity-2d and gnome-session are not working anymore with xrdp since Ubuntu 12.10.  Unity-2d does not exists in Ubuntu 14.04. xrdp and gnome session are not working well together.

So to be able to use xrdp and Ubuntu 14.04 is to install an alternate desktop interface that will be used while connected through xrdp.

step 1 - install xrdp

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Step 2 - install alternate desktop (we will install mate-desktop because similar to gnome 2 desktop)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
```

Step 3 - tell xrdp to use the mate-desktop when performing remote desktop session

```
echo mate-session >~/.xsession
```

**Update info - Important:**

witht the final release of ubuntu 16.04, **Step 3** seems not to work anymore. To be able to connect via remote desktop and access the mate desktop, you will need to 
modify the /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh.  add after the fi line the following command

```
mate-session
```

Save it and give it a try.  You should then be able to access your remote desktop

Reference links [Install xrdp on Ubuntu 16.04](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952)

Comment: Would like to confirm this one. 

Works well for me ~!

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
Enter the tty
```

and type this in

```
startx
```

and then this from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity2d
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yaunnu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and it might work fine this way.