# 14.04 xrdp gnome-session (of any sort) does not work

Tags: 14.04, gnome, remote-desktop, rdp, xrdp

I have spent the evening trying to get xrdp working...

None of these ~/.xsession options work - the connection starts, but then crashes

```
gnome-session -–session=Ubuntu-2d
gnome-session -–session=gnome-fallback
```

This question is similer:
[14.04.3 xrdp "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" not Work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680413/14-04-3-xrdp-gnome-session-session-ubuntu-2d-not-work)
But has no answer.

I have found a solution, using xfce4 instead of gnome, but I would prefer not to have to use two different shells for one system.

Is there any gnome session that does work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with xrdp and Ubuntu.  If you want to use xrdp with Ubuntu 12.10 and later, you will need to install an alternative desktop environment.  the ubuntu-2d does not exists anymore and the gnome-fallback has also some issues.

The best option so far is to install an alternative shell.  You can install mate-desktop interface (which look like the gnome 2 interface)

so to summarize:

Step 1 - install xrdp

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Step 2 - Install mate-desktop

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
```

Step 3 - the `.xsession` file should contain `mate-session`

Full instructions for Ubuntu 15.10 can be found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8498).